# Clarification about Heisenberg’s 1925 paper and the Bohr-Sommerfeld rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history, quantization

I am reading Heisenberg's 1925 paper and there is one point that I feel is crucial yet not explained well enough.

After he establishes $x(t)$ as a matrix, calculates $x(t)^{2}$, and talks about non-commutativity, he talks about how one would go about calculating $x(t)$. 
In that section, he talks about the Bohr-Sommerfeld condition $J = nh$.
He says that this condition does not fit naturally into the dynamical calculations laid out.

From here: http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/SQM261.pdf

> [image]

A similar point is mentioned on page 6 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0404009.pdf

> Heisenberg argues that $(14)$ does not sit well with the Correspondence Principle, since the latter should only determine $J$ up to an additive constant (times $h$). Setting $(14)$ equal to $nh$, he converts it to the form $(H(15))$.

---

What exactly is meant by the phrase that the Bohr-Sommerfeld condition does not sit well with the correspondence principle? Why should it only hold up to an additive constant? Is there a way to spell out this argument in more detail?

Comment: I have a guess, but I could be wrong. Could it be a zero point energy term? Nowadays we use a specific prescription to order operators so we can define it consistently, including the value for 0 excitations, so maybe this is an statement about this term.